# Understanding Integral

Tags: integration

I have the following integral:
$$(h*F)(t)=\int_0^t h(t-x)dF(x).$$
I found in the internet that I can write this integral as:
$$\int_0^t h(t-x)dF(x)=\int_0^t h(t-x)F(x)dx.$$
Is that right? Or how do I have to understand it?

In my literature I found that I can consider it as follow:
$$\int_0^t h(t-x)dF(x)=\int_0^t h(t-x)F'(x)dx.$$
So I'm now very confused. Can anybody help me here? That would be great!

And a second question, is the follwing equality satisfied (if I take the second form):
$$\int_0^t h(t-x)F'(x)dx=\int_0^t h(x)F'(t-x)dx.$$
I would say yes, then I can subtituate. But I'm not sure since $F'(x)$ is confusing me.

Comment: Have you heard of the [Riemann Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)?

Comment: Generally, $\int dF(x) = \int F'(x) dx$ which is sometimes written as $\int f(x) dx$ where $f(x) = F'(x)$. But I've never seen $\int dF(x) = \int F(x)dx$.

Comment: You should check the **convolution product**. You can find it in all context about Harmonic Analysis and in the following link.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Comment: Ok thank you so far!
yes i have seen the article about convolution.
I have the follwinig definition for $h:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
$$(h*F)(t):=\int_0^t h(t-x)dF(x).$$
So can I then do the following:
$$(h*F)(t)=\int_0^t h(t-x)dF(x)=\int_0^t h(t-x)F'(x) dx=\int_0^t h(x)F'(t-x) dx ?$$